# How to stop back behavior of Intent redirection?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-studio, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

Suppose that I have 2 pages A and B. On click on a link on A, I redirect my app to page B. This page B just redirects to an App by setting `window.location=<web_intent_link>` using intents. The problem is that after doing this chrome automatically redirects back to page A. How can I make chrome remain on page B.

How to replicate

1. Make sure you have Instagram installed
2. Goto https://namaggarwal.github.io/open_test_links/intent.html
3. Click on Instagram
4. It redirects to a different page then opens Instagram while redirecting to original page.

Code is available here

intent.html (A)

```
<a href="/open_test_links/redirect_insta_intent.html">Instagram</a>
```

redirect_insta_intent.html (B)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function redirect() {
        window.location = "intent://instagram.com/_u/namaggarwal/#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;scheme=https;end"
      }
      (function(){
        redirect();
      })()
    </script>
```

Comment: Please include relevant code snippets in your question as contents of repositories can change and offsite links may break in the future.

Comment: In your Activity B, if you use webview, then write this code inside onDestory function - if (webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }

Comment: its not an activity.. its a webpage opened in chrome